# How to get a pair of element from a list with certain condition?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

Let us consider the following example :

```
n=int(raw_input('Enter an integer n= '))
L=range(n)
V=[]

for i in L:
    print i
    for j in L:
    if (j!=i) and (i==(n*j)%n or j==(n*i)%n)
            V.append((i,j))
```

The elements of M should like the form M=[(i,j),...]

The above code gave me errors. How can I fix this.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: indentation errors you mean ?

Comment: Your code is working fine, Its just the indentation error and I think you forgot to add `:` end of `if`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Primo.Raj. Please take the [tour], read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You can fix this by reading the errors, they often clearly tell you what the problem is

Comment: Do not start learning Python 2 in 2018.

Comment: It shows the errors :  File "test.py", line 8
    if (j!=i) and (i==(n*j)%n or j==(n*i)%n)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MrT Please undo your edit, edits are not meant to correct the posted code.

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank you all

Comment: _"My problem is solved."_ do you mean that you buried your Python 2 course and started with Python3 ;-)